# How to search for a cell using the value and obtain the index number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has 4 columns. 
Let's say: Test_Name, Runtime, Memory, Location

I want to find all the Test_Name = 'my_test' and replace the Location value with 'my_test_location'

So, effectively, it should search for all the test_names that match my search query and in those rows, replace the location field with the string i'm giving as input.

I know i can do this by iterating over every row. I want to know if an inbuilt function exists that can do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Original Dataframe:

[image]

Find all testcases with name = 'peter' and replace location field with '/work/peter'

Final Dataframe:

[image]

Comment: `df.loc[df.Test_Name.eq('peter'),'Location']= '/work/peter'`

Comment: `df.loc[df['Test_Name'] == my_test, 'Location'] = my_test_location`

Answer (score 1):

Dude try `.loc` and `.iloc`

```
df.loc[df.Test_Name == "my_test", "Location"] = "my_test_location"
```

Adding [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for `loc`

Comment: There's no `iloc` in your answer, Dude.